# Mysql Foreign key (150 foreign key constraint incorrectly formed )

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

```
create table Bands(
    band_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    band_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    band_year int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (band_ID)
);

create table Albums(
    album_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    album_name varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    band_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (album_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (band_name) REFERENCES Bands(band_name)
);
```

Can someone please help me with my MySQL statement? I thought a first it was conflicting types buts that's not the case. I'm not sure what's causing the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the column being referrred by the constraint either to be the primary key of the referred table (best practice) or at least to have an index.

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

Bottom line : why not store (and reference) the band id in the albums table instead of the band name? It seems to be like this would better respond to your use case.